# How to change header ornament symbol color in "elegantbook"?

Tags: header-footer

I would like to change  color of  the ornament symbol of the header of the  documentclass "elegantbook".  How to change page number style from  "-7-"  to   "7"?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[lang=en,11pt]{elegantbook}

%--------------------------------------------------
%Header Ornamenty
%--------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\quad\decofourleft\decoone\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}

%.................................................................................


\title{This is  Sample Title}
\subtitle{Classic Book}

\author{Author's Name}
\institute{Author's  Institution}
\date{\today}
\version{3.10}
\bioinfo{Bio}{Information}

\extrainfo{Victory won\rq t come to us unless we go to it. }

\logo{logo-blue.png}
\cover{cover.jpg}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{This is first Chapter}
Chapter contents here.

\newpage 
\section{First section}
Section  contents here.

\newpage 
\subsection{First section}
Subsection  contents here.

\end{document}
```

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: Only the ornament colour, or also the head rule?

Comment: @ Bernard  head rule also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to read elegantbook-en.pdf and the colours are all in there.
You need to look at elegantbook.cls to change the header number.

```
\documentclass[lang=en,11pt]{elegantbook}

\fancyhead[R]{\color{structurecolor}\thepage}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\renewcommand\headrule{\hrulefill
    \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\color{structurecolor}\quad\decofourleft\decoone\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is first Chapter}
Chapter contents here.

\newpage 
\section{First section}
Section  contents here.

\newpage 
\subsection{First section}
Subsection  contents here.

\end{document}
```